# Особенности работы сессий laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет. Планирую делать корзину для интернет-магазина. Не понимаю некоторые особенности сессий у laravel (драйвер - файловая система). Несколько вопросов:

1. После окончания времени жизни сессии, она удаляется полностью и пользователь получает пустую корзину? Или же она регенерируется и пользователь этого не видит? Если удаляется, то есть ли смысл ставить время жизни сессии = неделя?
2. Что правильнее: хранить данные о товарах в корзине в сессии или в куках пользователя?
3. Как лучше сделать корзину: создать отдельную модель или сделать отдельный пакет для неё? Пакеты еще ни разу не создавал, поэтому точно не знаю, как правильнее поступить в данном случае.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Не в ответ и не в обиду, но сейчас, насколько я знаю, тенденция не юзать сессию

Comment: @Daniil раз вы говорите что тенденция такая, то обоснуйте свои доводы.

Comment: @АлександрСемикашев, я не прошу следовать моим наблюдениям, только лишь поделился ими, если вас почему-то удивило это, можете поресёчить что касается этой темы и сделать для себя правильный вывод.

Comment: 1) после протухания сессии, сам файл сессии остается, но у пользователя появится новая и как следствие - новая корзина 2) лучше на мой взгляд хранить данные о сложенных товарах в корзине, а в куках только идетификатор сессии 3) модели корзины вполне будет достаточно